# Как получить и преобразовать строку таблицы в массив на Postgres c?

Tags: c, postgresql

Мне по определённой причине надо написать расширение на Си для Postgres. В чем проблема - следую документации самого Postgres: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.4/xfunc-c

А как взять строку таблицы (рандомной вообще) и преобразовать ее в массив, чтобы с ней работать?
Да, я вижу, что есть вот это:

`HeapTupleHeader t = PG_GETARG_HEAPTUPLEHEADER(0);`

Окей, получаем текущую строку, после этого в документации написано, что можно вызвать `GETATTRIBUTEBYNAME` - а что если я не знаю имя? Допустим, есть `GetAttributeByNum` - номер колонки, но откуда я могу знать сколько колонок в строке таблицы? Разве что не задавать конкретно как `int columnNumber = PG_GETARG_INT32(1)`, тогда, наверное, можно пройтись циклом.

Суть: я запуталась и в документации, и в Си, и в Postgres, и мне нужно небольшое разъяснение по этому поводу.

Answer (score 1):

У серверного Си'шного API постгреса документацией являются его хедеры и исходники... Одни говорят, что другой и не надо, а другие, что это называется «её просто нет», но, по факту, читать их всё равно придётся. К тому что есть на сайте стоит относится не более чем как к общему обзору.

---

Для ответа на конкретные вопросы достаточно просто взглянуть на реализацию той же [`GetAttributeByName()`](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/execUtils_8c.html#ac7de9629c5bfbf1c4734824f03a5e281):

> Допустим, есть GetAttributeByNum - номер колонки, но откуда я могу знать сколько колонок в строке таблицы?

```
#include <server/utils/typcache.h>
// ...
TupleDesc tupDesc = lookup_rowtype_tupdesc(tupType, tupTypmod);
int n = tupDesc->natts;
```

> Окей, получаем текущую строку, после этого в документации написано, что можно вызвать GETATTRIBUTEBYNAME - а что если я не знаю имя?

Перебрать имена после этого можно как-то так:

```
for (i = 0; i < tupDesc->natts; i++) {
    Form_pg_attribute att = TupleDescAttr(tupDesc, i);
    char *name = &(att->attname);
    // ...
 }
```

Comment: Спасибо за подкинутую идею почитать исходники) Смотрю на json.c и не понимаю, что происходит. Ок, вижу row_to_json() - получается они получают первую строку таблицы, ее парсят (разбивают на значения, распределяют по категориям и записывают в result) и возвращают джейсонку? А как эта функция представлена в самом постгресе? типа create or replace function row_to_json(anyelement)?

Comment: это встроенная функция, так что на SQL её определения как такового скорей всего не будет... так что чтобы понять, как именно она вызывается, надо в потроха сервера глубже закапываться...